# java.lang.NullPointerException on Async Task in Android

Tags: android, email, android-asynctask

I want to send email without using Email Clients option. I have my own Custom Email View .
I download the idea from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) . And it is giving os Network exception. so for this i use asynctask and run it but i receive errors in Logcat

EmailSend.java:

```
public class EmailSend extends Activity{


Mail m ;


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 



    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view) { 

            new ListViewContactsLoader().execute();

        } 
    }); 
} 



/** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{    

    public ListViewContactsLoader() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try { 
            // m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

            if(m.send()) { 
                Toast.makeText(EmailSend .this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                return true;
            } else { 
                Toast.makeText(EmailSend .this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                return false;
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 

            return false;
        }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {          
        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview



    }   

    public void onPreExecute() {

        Mail m = new Mail("user@gmail.com", ""); 

        String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body.");
    }


}
```

}

Manifest File:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

LogCat:

```
   Could not send email

           java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.example.emailer.EmailSend$ListViewContactsLoader.doInBackground(EmailSend.java:54)

at com.example.emailer.EmailSend$ListViewContactsLoader.doInBackground(EmailSend.java:1)

at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is giving os Network exception

because currently you are trying to show `Toast` messages from `doInBackground`(from on  UI Thread) method. use `onPostExecute` method for showing Toast messages because this method called on UI Thread. try it as :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {          
        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
         if(result){
           // show Toast Message here
          }else{
           // show Toast Message here
           }
         //.....your code here...
    }
```

**EDIT :** you are getting `NullPointerException` probably you forget to initialize `m` object of `Mail` class before using it. initialize `m` object inside `onPreExecute` as instead of creating new instance again :

```
public void onPreExecute() {

    m = new Mail("user@gmail.com", ""); 
  ......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onPreExecute() {

    this.m = new Mail("user@gmail.com", ""); 

    String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"}; 
    m.setTo(toArr); 
    m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
    m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
    m.setBody("Email body.");
}


}
```

You can't make anather instance!

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated  local variable Mail m = new Mail("user@gmail.com", ""); inside `onPreExecute` but then you use `if(m.send()) {` inside `doInBackground`

`Mail m` should be attribute of class `ListViewContactsLoader`

Something like:

```
public void onPreExecute() {
        m = new Mail("user@gmail.com", "");
```

and

```
   private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{  
       private Mail m;
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is giving os Network exception

Because you are trying update/display on UI from `doInBackground()` which isn't possible directly.

To resolve this issue, you can do either one of the following:

1. Display Toast message from onPostExecute()
2. or implement `runOnUiThread()` if you want to update UI from `doInBackground()` any how.

For example:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(EmailSend .this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
```